# Continuous Integration for Teradata Projects

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, teradata

I am looking to develop a continuous integration system for Teradata projects. We have more than 100 teradata projects manually migrating the code to different environments. I am trying to automate this process using Jenkins. Goal is to pull the infa workflows, spl, ddl, dml or script files from SVN for each project and execute them on the target server. Any pointers?

Comment: Can someone provide some inputs?

Comment: We're all volunteers here. I'm not sure whether bumping really helps to get a quick answer to such a broad question.

Comment: I just meant to bring it to the notice if someone had missed seeing this post who has an idea on this. Thanks for your comment. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

With *"the code to different environments"* you mean SPL, DDL, DML, scripts, right? What do you mean by *"infa workflows"*?

Do you  already have a Jenkins running?

To execute a job on an other host (*"server"*) the host must be established as a Jenkins node (JVM and Jenkins' `slave.jar` is all you need for that). If you don't want to install and run this on your servers you could execute [SSHEXEC](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) (or whatever your systems support) in a job running on the Jenkins master. Though I'd prefer the node variant. Managing Jenkins nodes is more convenient, IMHO.